# Retrieve list from request in django

Tags: python, django, post

how can I put json list to **POST** request in **django**?

I'm using `render` method to show data on my site and then edit it with **vue** framework.

```
render(request, self.template_name, {
       "form": self.form_class(request.user),
       "json_data": json.dumps(data),
       "keys": json.dumps(keys),
})
```

Lists in vue look like this

```
<script>
  {% autoescape off %}
    let keys = {{ keys }};
    let json_data = {{ json_data }};
  {% endautoescape %}
</script>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
    data: {
        keys: keys,
        json_data: json_data,
    },
...
</script>
```

How can I send edited list to another view using form tags?

```
<form action="{% url 'edit' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" name="confirm" class="btn btn-primary">
      {% bootstrap_icon "circle-arrow-right" %} {% trans "Next" %}
    </button>
  {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this problem. You just have to use

```
<input type="hidden" name="json_data" :value="json_data">
```

instead of

```
<input type="hidden" name="json_data" value=[[ json_data ]]>
```

in form tags